# Call to a member function random on null en Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, random, null

Estoy realizando un proyecto de prueba para mi aprendizaje de Laravel en su versión 5.7

Estoy en la parte de lanzar un seeder para, con todo lo configurado en los factories, los modelos y el DatabaseSeeder, se creen datos aleatorios en la base de datos para así, poder hacer pruebas en tareas de desarrollo.

Pues bien, al ejecutar el comando para lanzar el seeder:

`php artisan db:seed`

me sale este ERROR del que no tengo idea de cómo resolver o darle solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como digo, no sé como resolver el error y en el tiempo que he invertido buscando por Internet, no he encontrado nada al respecto.

El contenido del `database/facories/CursoFactory.php` es éste:

```
<?php

use App\Profesor;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This directory should contain each of the model factory definitions for
| your application. Factories provide a convenient way to generate new
| model instances for testing / seeding your application's database.
|
*/

$factory->define(App\Curso::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    ////$profesores = Profesor::all();
    /**
     * Mejor que la anterior, poner como sigue:
     * para que no se consulte y se cargue la lista de nuevo cada vez que se genere
     * una instancia de Curso, lo que causaría lentitud en el proceso, se puede poner
     * la variable a STATIC
     */
    //static $profesores = Profesor::all();
    /**
     * y como a las variables STATIC no se les puede asignar, directamente, un valor,
     * se deberá codificar de esta forma:
     */
    static $profesores;
    //Condicional ternario de no hacer nada si la variable ya tiene un valor (?vacío)
    //y, sino (:), se le asigna uno
    ////$profesores ?: Profesor::all();
    //o a través del ISSET, si es una variable ya establecida, su valor es igual a si mismo,
    //sino, se le asigna un valor
    isset($profesores) ? $profesores : Profesor::all();

    return [
            //sentence, para frases aleatorias  || mt_ran(2,4) para generar un núm. de 2 a 4 palabras
        'titulo' => $faker->sentence(mt_rand(2,4)),
            //paragraph, generar párrafos(de 4 componentes, es decir, ¿4 líneas?)
        'descripcion' => $faker->paragraph(4),
        'profesor_id' => $profesores->random()->id,
    ];
});
```

El error se produce en la línea de:

`'profesor_id' => $profesores->random()->id,`

Pero la supuesta carga de la variable `$profesores` es algo más arriba, dónde, estableciéndola como `static`, se ha querido considerar de dos formas diferentes, si la variable está cargada o no para darle si no lo está, un valor por defecto.
De alguna forma, ninguno de los condicionales se lleva a cabo y, por ello, la variable llega al `random()` con un `null` cosa que el `random()` no admite y, por ello, se produce el ERROR.

¿Alguien sabría que hacer para evitar el fallo mostrado?

Gracias. Saludos ...

---

---

### EDITADO

Si aplico la solución propuesta en el comentario sobre sustituir esto

```
'profesor_id' => $profesores->random()->id,
```

por esto

```
'profesor_id' => $profesores::random()->id,
```

entonces, me salta este otro ERROR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

---

### EDITADO (2ª)

Puede que no se haya entendido el planteamiento del problema. Es verdad que puse que el error se produce aquí, en esta línea:

`'profesor_id' => $profesores->random()->id,`

Pero, más bien quise decir que es ahí dónde salta o se refleja, finalmente, el error. Y la línea que se señala en la terminal.

Pero dónde el ERROR tiene el origen es en cualquiera de las dos posibles condicionales que me  gustaría emplear, es decir, si habilito la carga de la variable `$profesores` por medio de una de las dos condicionales

bien sea a través de

```
    static $profesores;
    $profesores ?: Profesor::all();
```

o a través de

```
    static $profesores;
    isset($profesores) ? $profesores : Profesor::all();
```

Es, entonces, cuando salta el ERROR de "*Call to a member function random() on null*", en las veces que habilito alguno de los condicionales.

Si no uso la carga condicional de la variable y le asigno, en toda ocasión, el resultado de la consulta, no se produce el ERROR.

```
    static $profesores;
    $profesores = Profesor::all();

    ...

'profesor_id' => $profesores->random()->id,
```

Pero yo lo que pretendía era controlar la carga de la variable estática `$profesores` de tal forma que si ya estuviera cargada, no hacer nada y si no lo estuviera, entonces, pasarle la colección resultante de `Profesor::all()`.

Espero que ahora quede más claro el problema. Saludos.

Comment: La variable $profesores esta declarada como static. Por lo tanto, en caso de que estuviera bien definida, no podrias acceder al metodo `random()` con el operador ->, tendrias que utilizar `::`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero haciendo ese cambio, entonces, me salta otro error (como se ve en la imagen que acabo de subir).

Comment: Puedes tratar usando un `rand(1, 9)`

Answer (score 1):

Para establecer una relación con una entidad aleatoriamente yo utilizo esto:

```
'profesor_id' => App\Profesor::find(rand(1,10))->id,
```

Explicando un poco el por qué del error creo que puede ser porque el método random() retorna un Collection, quiere decir que deberías usar first() al final para obtener una instancia de Profesor. La linea completa sería:

```
'profesor_id' => $profesores->random()->first()->id,
```

Comment: Hola acron.bn, esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, pero sería ideal que la explicaras un poco. Por ejemplo: indicando las diferencias con lo que tiene el usuario y por qué funcionaría. Lee [answer] para más información. Saludos.

Comment: Con la solución de aplicar el `'profesor_id' => $profesores->random()->first()->id,` siempre, para todos los registros de pruebas obtengo el mismo profesor y ese no es el objetivo sino que de entre toda la lista el RANDOM escogiera uno de los IDs al azar, no siempre el primero. Voy a editar otra vez la pregunta porque, igual, no esta del todo claro el problema que planteaba ...

Comment: Hola zacktagnan, de momento se resolvió el problema del null. La segunda solución que dí devuelve elementos random de la colección, no el mismo, ya lo comprobé. En todo caso, collection tienen un método shuffle() que reordena al azar los items de la colección, lo puedes ver en la documentación de laravel, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-shuffle . Otra opción es usar la primera solución que te propuse. Son equivalentes aunque no he analizado el impacto en rendimiento. Saludos.